# Migrate clearcase to perforce

Tags: migration, perforce, clearcase

I have a large quantity of clearcase data which needs to be migrated into perforce.  The revisions span the better part of a decade and I need to preserve as much branch and tag information as possible.  Additionally we make extensive use of symbolic links, supported in clearcase but not in perforce.  What advice or tools can you suggest which might make this easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to decide if you need to migrate everything, or just certain key versions.  If you only migrate the important versions (releases and major milestones) you'll end up with a much simpler history in Perforce, without losing anything important.  Then ClearCase can be keep as a historical archive in case it is ever needed.  (Unless IBM has changed things ClearCase licenses do not expire when maintainance runs out, you just lose the right to new upgrades and patches and acces to support)

Keep in mind that Perforce does not version control directories and does not keep a full per-element version tree - this means a 1:1 with exact results is going to be impossible.  Recreating the important snapshots is a much more achievable goal; keeping everything may be impossible, as Perforce lacks features ClearCase relies upon.

To see what Perforce says about the miration, check out
http://perforce.com/perforce/ccaseconv.html
This explains the key differences and covers a few approaches you can take.

Answer (score 2):

Start by doing a Google search on ["clearcase to perforce conversion"](http://www.google.com/search?q=clearcase+to+perforce+conversion).
Then read the [ClearCase to Perforce Conversion Guide](http://perforce.com/perforce/ccaseconv.html).
Once you're done crying, you're going to have to decide (1) how much effort you can afford, and (2) what you really need to capture as part of the conversion.  You're not going to get it all, so you might as well just focus on getting the important branches.

Another consideration would be to just capture the current state of each supported branch as a snapshot, import that into Perforce, and then turn off the old ClearCase server, saving it in a known good state for that day when you need to access something from the deep, dark, pre-Perforce days...

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are outdated. Now you can import CC->Perforce with many options also preserving history.
http://www.perforce.com/sites/default/files/pdf/migration-planning-guide-clearcase-to-perforce.pdf

Answer (score 0):

What you also have to keep in mind is the fact, that your importerscript may slightly commit in another sequence than the clearcase commits(maybe you are traversing dir, may be histories of files, etc.)

So, unless you gather all version information into a (large) database and sort them afterwards, you will end up with commits which are not very useful to look into(except of course history of single files). As you (hopefully) change your commit-policy to commit atomic changes into perforce, it will be visible when development started: The commits before just do not make any sense on a project scope.

So you really should think of leaving clearcase history behind. Tags/Branches creation is also a different problem, as you need your old configspecs for your old branches.
At the end you will get wrong filenames in old tags(as perforce do not support dir-vers.) so you will use clearcase for this(and it is *very* tricky to get the correct filename for each version of a file!).

The last problem you will encounter: importer run time:
if you have large VOBs(eg. 10 years, 50 GB size), you will wait days for the importer to gather all information and convert it to a nice shiny perforce repo. All this day your devteam will stop working.

Comment: Much of the data extracted from Clearcase can be cached, so you can do a lot of the preparation ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note on the one import I saw from ClearCase to Perforce.
As noted in the [ClearCase to Perforce Conversion Guide](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/ccaseconv.html):

> Perforce supports atomic change transactions; ClearCase doesn't.
>
> Note that labels are often used to simply denote a snapshot in time for a particular easily-specified set of files; this is inherently easy to do in Perforce without using a label, due to Perforce's use of atomic change transactions and file naming syntax.
> For example, the state of all the files in `//depot/projecta` as of change 42 can be obtained with

```
p4 sync //depot/projecta/...@42
```

That means the ClearCase project that got imported was an **[UCM one](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/c_hood_ucm_concepts.htm)**, since the concept of baseline closely follows the one of global revision.
Only files with a baseline on them were imported, the other versions were discarded.