# switch branches without checkout in GIT

Tags: git, branch

Here are the steps that I have followed:

1. Created a repository
2. added a file to the `master` branch.
3. created a branch called `test_branch`.
4. added close to 30k files in the `test_branch` & committed.
5. now when I try to switch to `master` branch. 
   It says "`checking out files:  83% (24967/30002)`", and now I have all the files which I have committed in `test_branch` in my `master` branch as well.

Why I am getting this error, and how to overcome it ?

Comment: what does `git status` say before step 5? It might help if you copy the whole output of your prompt.

Comment: Nothing to commit. working directory is clean

Answer (score 1):

1. created a branch called test_branch

How did you make it? Have you checked if you have checked it out? There are two commands to do it - `git branch` will NOT checkout it and `git checkout -b` will.

Comment: ya i created a branch using git branch test_branch & then git checkout test_branch.

Answer (score 0):

For such large volume of files in one branch, as opposed to the other, it might be better to clone the repository (which should reference by default the `master` branch), while leaving your first repo on the `test_branch`.

Comment: do you mean to say if i have 10 branches in my clearcase vob & if i wish to replicate the same in GIT I need to create 10 repositories?

Comment: @Ankita: To import a ClearCase repo into git, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546682/moving-from-clearcase-to-mercurial-your-top-tips/2546878#2546878. You need to reorganize your data and not import everything in one repo. My answer alludes to one repo cloned multiple times, but again, for an export from a CVCS (Centralized VCS) like ClearCase, you need to export parts of the ClearCase repo into several Git repos.

Comment: @ VonC : I tried a very simple thing. I have set a view & what ever is there in that view, I have copied that in one of the branches of GIT repo. When I switch branches, I am getting this error. Can't git handle large number of file ?

Comment: @Ankita: Git can handle large number of files, but not all types of files (large number of binaries for example would be problematic)

Comment: @Vonc : can GIT handle .properties & .xml file ?

Comment: @Ankita: sure. Any text file will do. Binary too, but not in *too many* occurences, and/or not too large (as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762413/is-git-worth-for-managing-many-files-bigger-than-500mb/1762695#1762695 )

Comment: @Vonc : Why files are being checkout when i am switching branches. ? I havn't committed in the master branch, still files are appearing in master branch.

Comment: @Ankita: but you say you have committed those file in your question.

Comment: @Vonc : I have committed on test_branch but not in master branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the working dir unchanged, use `git reset --soft <tree-ish>`. To make branches point wherever you want without having to check them out, use `git update-ref refs/heads/branch_name <tree-ish>` where tree-ish could be `head^`, `master^2~3`, `other_branch`, `other_branch@{"2 days ago"}`, etc.

Hope this helps.