# Git Quota Limits

Tags: git

Does Git have a limit on how much data can be stored in a first push? I am moving all of my websites into Git, some are years old of data. I downloaded the site, created a repository and ran

```
$ git add .
```

At some point it will say the nothing can be written to the index. Basically locking it up and nothing can go through. Is there something I am missing?

The total size of the site is 1GB, I am sure i could cut that down, but it's a lot of user PDFs and media presentations. Is Git my true solution, or is mercurial?

Comment: It's just "Git", not "GIT", and can you please post your exist error message?

Comment: After adding some of the .js files or larger groups in 1 shot, I got fatal: index file corrupt

Comment: Seems the issue was our ubuntu server, this is our first attempt at using any version control, I downloaded a copy to my local machine with no problems. The server had a older version of git on it, and it was mounted via afp, just not sure what the issue was.

Answer (score 2):

Git does not have any *theoretical* limits on the number of files, or the total size of files, in a commit or repository.

However, there are defiantly **practical** limits to the size of the repository - [Linus Torvalds](http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds) mentions these in a message [here](http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-05/msg00051.html).

As the size of the repository grows, the time taken to do things will also grow. There's a few answers about that, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984707/what-are-the-git-limits/984763#984763).

There's also a few questions which suggest that physical limitations (memory, specifically) can impose limits on some actions in a repository - there's a thread about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918672/why-does-git-pm-on-cygwin-complain-about-out-of-memory-during-large-request), although these kinds of issues may be addressed through workarounds in git.

Addressing the question: from the comments, the error that you're getting `fatal: index file corrupt` isn't related to the aggregate size of files you're trying to add to the index.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason might be that your pack file (which is how git saves snapshots) exceeds your underlying file systems maximum file size. I believe that is 4GB for FAT32, for example. If that is the case, a setting of, say, 200MB for `pack.packSizeLimit` might solve your problem.

Another possible reason might be ownership/permission issues. Like, you did `git init` as root but try to `git add` as regular user.