# git plugin and hudson

Tags: git, scripting, continuous-integration, hudson

I using Hudson as my continuous integrations tool. Now when pulling down sources from multiple git repositories. I am getting errors in my workspace only pulling down the last repository in the list and the build fails.

I understand that when pull down from multiple git repositories multiple hidden `.git` directories are created in my workspace. The git plugin doesn't specify a way from me to pull each repository into its own directory within the workspace. How do I achieve this? I am using the latest [git plugin tool](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Git+Plugin)

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather use the [Hudson Git plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Git+Plugin) the way it naturally runs: pulling only one Git repo.

Except that Git repo could be a parent repo for **[submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)**, each submodule being of the Git repos you wanted to import into the Hudson jib workspace in the first place.

That is not an "easy" solution though, since a Git parent repo only references "fixed" point in the Git submodules history.
That means if you want the Git plugin to detect any changes, the submodules need to have new commit (normal) but the parent repo should also be committed to register the new Git submodules references.

Comment: whoa. so the only way your telling me to get multiple repositories  is to use submodules or have a giant repositories that contains everything that i pull down. :)

Comment: @garbagecollector: submodules are better as they don't change the nature of your current Git repositories: they stay the same. You only have to setup one extra level. Trying to get everything in one repo however [is not a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984707/what-are-the-git-limits/984973#984973).

Comment: has there been any progress on building git plugins without submodules?

Comment: @garbagecollector: not to my knowledge, no.