# Git: working with submodules

Tags: jenkins

How to configure Jenkins to use git repository with submodules?
I want to build even when change is pushed only to submodule.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct configuration for this.

Related question here - [git plugin and hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578088/git-plugin-and-hudson)

tl;dr - whenever your submodule has a change (which is of course committed), make sure you make a commit on your main git repository as well to register the git submodule's changes; the build will then kick in accordingly.