# Getting started with Eclipse + EGit - confused

Tags: eclipse, git

I am used to using Eclipse with SVN and CVS.

Now I want to use GIT via EGIT.

The goal is to have a local repository, not in the eclipse work-space, that my changes go into. That way, I can make changes, commit them, and have a repository with the changes that I can back up (at least, that's how it works in SVN).

Following the user's guide, I find it creates the repository within my Eclipse project in the workspace, which is recommended against. What am I missing?

Steps:

- Create a Java project in Eclipse (Test)
- On Project right click->Team->Share Project->Git
- ...Next - shows "Configure Git Repository" Panel
  ...the only repository it will let me create is inside the project.

Huh?

Answer (score 2):

You can create multiple projects under one repo in EGit, see http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Creating_a_Git_Repository_for_multiple_Projects  In that case, EGit will do it automatically.

You can also use the Git Repository view to create an empty git repo outside of the workspace.  See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Creating_a_Repository  After that, you can create new java projects and specify the external git repo subdirectory as their location.

Answer (score 0):

Since:

- you can [create a java project outside of the workspace](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#firstjava_project)
  (see option "`create project form existing source`": the `.project` and `.classpath` will be created in the parent directory of the directory you will select as containing the sources)
- Egit will create the `.git` where the `.project` and `.classpath` are created

you will have a repo outside of the Eclipse workspace.

Comment: This still leaves me with the repository inside the project, although outside the workspace. I guess I wasn't clear enough. I want a repository with all my projects in it, not all my projects with repositories in them. Is a "push" each time the only way to do that? If so, that is much less useful than svn, where a commit puts my changes into an external repository.

Comment: @SChaser: it is usually preferable to have separate repository per project. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984707/what-are-the-git-limits/984973#984973. Egit doesn't, as far as I know, offer the possibility to version several projects within *one* repo.

Comment: thanks for your answers. That isn't quite the issue. What I want is to be able to have the git "local repository" outside my eclipse project in an arbitrary directory. Then I can have all my local repositories under a single parent directory which is a convenient place to back up from. My usage pattern is unusual because I am working as an individual rather than a collaborator, so the local repositories are adequate as my master directories.