# How to work with git?

Tags: git, maven, clearcase

We are migrating from Clearcase to GIT.
We are 18 people divide into 4 teams: GUI team, Server side team, buisness logic team and web team.

So far we had streams:

```
       1. version 1
                    1.a. Stream for gui
                               1.a. redesing feature stream
                    1.b. Stream for web
                    1.c. Stream for serverside
                               1.a. refactor feature stream
                    1.d. Stream for business logic
       2. version 2
                    1.a. Stream for gui
                    1.b. Stream for web
                    1.c. Stream for serverside
                    1.d. Stream for business logic
```

Now, since the code that each team works on  is different than the others - i thougt about seperating them all into different repositories, and publishing only jars/wars (artificats) using maven.
However, there needs some more work to get to there.

So I want all of us to have a shared repository -
My question is how it is recommended for an organization like ours to work???
I mean branch wise. Also with what tools - source tree, git flow?
And what conventions may be good for us?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, check the [differences between ClearCase and Git in my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645771/6309).

There is no notion of UCM Stream in git, only branches.
The UCM ClearCase component is typically a Git repo.

I would recommend starting with a simple branch workflow model, and as many Git repositories as you have components.

You want a shared Git repos server, not a "shared repository" (because trying to [fit all files in one giant repo won't work well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/984973/6309)).
Make sure you are not storing large binary files in a git repo either.

You can see a more [complete workflow with JGit-Flow](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/maven-git-flow-plugin-for-better-releases/) complete with a [`maven-jgitflow-plugin`](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/maven-jgitflow-plugin/wiki/Home), if you have a java project with maven ([repo here](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jgit-flow)).
That enables support for git-flow style releases via maven.