# Impact of large number of branches in a git repo?

Tags: git

Does anyone know what the impact is of a git repo that has a lot of branches (2000+)? Does git pull or git fetch slow down due to having that many branches? Please provide benchmarks if there is a difference.

Comment: It is more a filesystem problem than a git one. If your branch are named with / it could be better. http://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-Internals-Git-References `find .git/refs/` will list all refs

Comment: A branch pointer in Git is 41 bytes large, 40 bytes of characters and an additional new line character. Therefore, the creating of branches in Git is very fast and cheap in terms of resource consumption.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As others have pointed out, branches and other refs are just files in the file system (except that's not quite true because of [packed refs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-refs)) and are pretty cheap, but that doesn't mean their number can't affect performance. See e.g. the [Poor push performance with large number of refs](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/261183) thread on the Git mailing list for a recent (Dec 2014) example of Git performance being affected by having 20k refs in a repository.

If I recall correctly, some part of the ref processing was O(n²) a few years ago but that can very well have been fixed since. There's a [repo-discuss thread from March 2012](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/repo-discuss/0JFJItxWVRY/discussion) that contains some potentially useful details, if perhaps dated and specific to JGit.

The also somewhat dated [Scaling Gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/wiki/Scaling) article talks about (among other things) potential problems with high ref counts, but also notes that several sites have gits with over 100k refs. We have a git with ~150k refs and I don't think we're seeing any performance issues with it.

One aspect of having lots of refs is the size of the ref advertisement at the start of some Git transactions. The size of the advertisement of aforementioned 150k ref git is about 10 MB, i.e. every single `git fetch` operation is going to download that amount of data.

So yes, don't ignore the issue completely but you shouldn't lose any sleep over a mere 2000 refs.

Answer (score 7):

March 2015: I don't have benchmarks but one way to ensure a [`git fetch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) remains reasonable even if the upstream repo has a large set of branches would be to specific a less general **[refspec](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)** than the one by default.

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

You can add as many fetch refspecs to a remote as you want, effectively replacing the catch-all refspec above with more specific specs to just include the branches you actually need (even though the remote repo has thousands of them)

```
fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
fetch = +refs/heads/br*:refs/remotes/origin/br*
fetch = +refs/heads/mybranch:refs/remotes/origin/mybranch
....
```

---

April 2018: `git fetch` will improve with Git 2.18 (Q2 2018).

See [commit 024aa46](https://github.com/git/git/commit/024aa4696c788eb1b07be53331f770605696ffba) (14 Mar 2018) by [Takuto Ikuta (`atetubou`)](https://github.com/atetubou).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5d806b7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d806b74d5223d0c19afd023fea3b321cc5bc717), 09 Apr 2018)</sup>

> ### fetch-pack.c: use oidset to check existence of loose object

> When fetching from a repository with large number of refs, because to
> check existence of each refs in local repository to packed and loose
> objects, 'git fetch' ends up doing a lot of `lstat(2)` to non-existing
> loose form, which makes it slow.
>
> Instead of making as many `lstat(2)` calls as the refs the remote side
> advertised to see if these objects exist in the loose form, first
> enumerate all the existing loose objects in hashmap beforehand and use
> it to check existence of them if the number of refs is larger than the
> number of loose objects.
>
> With this patch, the number of `lstat(2)` calls in `git fetch` is reduced
> from 411412 to 13794 for chromium repository, it has more than 480000
> remote refs.
>
> I took time stat of `git fetch` when fetch-pack happens for chromium
> repository 3 times on linux with SSD.
>
> ```
> * with this patch
> 8.105s
> 8.309s
> 7.640s
> avg: 8.018s
>
> * master
> 12.287s
> 11.175s
> 12.227s
> avg: 11.896s
> ```
>
> On my MacBook Air which has slower lstat(2).
>
> ```
> * with this patch
> 14.501s
>
> * master
> 1m16.027s
> ```
>
> `git fetch` on slow disk will be improved largely.

---

Note this **hashmap** used in packfile does improve with Git 2.24 (Q4 2019)

See [commit e2b5038](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e2b5038d8793a1d1f92b62dab82acc0d6b7dbcb7), [commit 404ab78](https://github.com/git/git/commit/404ab78e39fc74c4eb604b6003642ed264f687a6), [commit 23dee69](https://github.com/git/git/commit/23dee69f53cf5024ca79e0b707dcb03c63f33bef), [commit c8e424c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8e424c9c94d97b18cd335be17f32a8ce94a5b7f), [commit 8a973d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a973d0bb398d6d83d6c048acecc750d01bd7234), [commit 87571c3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/87571c3f71ba41d89eef5202f8589daa26f984ca), [commit 939af16](https://github.com/git/git/commit/939af16eac1608766273d3971598dbcc4fe09928), [commit f23a465](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f23a465132a22860684ac66052cf9a954a18e27d), [commit f0e63c4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f0e63c41139f8982add435536d39aff6f3d4ca98), [commit 6bcbdfb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6bcbdfb277bdc81b5ad6996b3fb005382a35c2ee), [commit 973d5ee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/973d5eea7455e1053842f7474c8ec34755f3525b), [commit 26b455f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26b455f21ed7e0c7b0e4e4e69b5ae48545597020), [commit 28ee794](https://github.com/git/git/commit/28ee7941280828f9e528bd8c5d0f6515a57e0c44), [commit b6c5241](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6c5241606e67b57470e86ccf547d4ab90008a1d), [commit b94e5c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b94e5c1df674eb4ec8fdeaaae1ad8df552cb5d70), [commit f6eb6bd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6eb6bdcf2719defc3d38e0e2712fa3e18d29e91), [commit d22245a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d22245a2e360d2e708ca37169be8eb5a5899b98d), [commit d0a48a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d0a48a0a1d0df49af2e5fd6a80b0d84776c285aa), [commit 12878c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12878c83516e3b82f31a20f1b5431b7ff607a8db), [commit e010a41](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e010a41216efd85eacc4c0711ea405de4fb20526) (06 Oct 2019) by [Eric Wong (`ele828`)](https://github.com/ele828).
Suggested-by: [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5efabc7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5efabc7ed9e57bb73159d1ad7739c508167ef24a), 15 Oct 2019)</sup>

For example:

> ### [`packfile`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d0a48a0a1d0df49af2e5fd6a80b0d84776c285aa): use `hashmap_entry` in `delta_base_cache_entry`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Wong</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> This `hashmap_entry_init` function is intended to take a `hashmap_entry` struct pointer, not a hashmap struct pointer.
>
> This was not noticed because `hashmap_entry_init` takes a "`void *`" arg instead of "`struct hashmap_entry *`", and the hashmap struct is larger and can be cast into a `hashmap_entry` struct without data corruption.
>
> This has the **beneficial side effect of reducing the size of a `delta_base_cache_entry` from 104 bytes to 72 bytes on 64-bit systems**.

---

Before Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), there was a logic to estimate how many objects are in the repository, which is mean to run once per process invocation, but it ran every time the estimated value was requested.

This is faster with Git 2.29:

See [commit 67bb65d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67bb65de5ddf008cb39206354ae4b7af66c05b6c) (17 Sep 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 221b755](https://github.com/git/git/commit/221b755f3a99f600d08441fc5436d0f2ffe57065), 22 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`packfile`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67bb65de5ddf008cb39206354ae4b7af66c05b6c): actually set `approximate_object_count_valid`
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Rasmus Villemoes</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> The `approximate_object_count()` function tries to compute the count only once per process. But ever since it was introduced in [8e3f52d778](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e3f52d77854a19cb3fd2adee40be84c8a8bdacc) (`find_unique_abbrev`: move logic out of `get_short_sha1()`, 2016-10-03, Git v2.11.0-rc0), we failed to actually set the "valid" flag, meaning we'd compute it fresh on every call.
>
> This turns out not to be *too* bad, because we're only iterating through the `packed_git` list, and not making any system calls. But since it may get called for every abbreviated hash we output, even this can add up if you have many packs.
>
> Here are before-and-after timings for a new perf test which just asks rev-list to abbreviate each commit hash (the test repo is linux.git, with commit-graphs):
>
> ```
> Test                            origin              HEAD
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 5303.3: rev-list (1)            28.91(28.46+0.44)   29.03(28.65+0.38) +0.4%
> 5303.4: abbrev-commit (1)       1.18(1.06+0.11)     1.17(1.02+0.14) -0.8%
> 5303.7: rev-list (50)           28.95(28.56+0.38)   29.50(29.17+0.32) +1.9%
> 5303.8: abbrev-commit (50)      3.67(3.56+0.10)     3.57(3.42+0.15) -2.7%
> 5303.11: rev-list (1000)        30.34(29.89+0.43)   30.82(30.35+0.46) +1.6%
> 5303.12: abbrev-commit (1000)   86.82(86.52+0.29)   77.82(77.59+0.22) -10.4%
> 5303.15: load 10,000 packs      0.08(0.02+0.05)     0.08(0.02+0.06) +0.0%
> ```
>
> It doesn't help at all when we have 1 pack (5303.4), but we get a 10% speedup when there are 1000 packs (5303.12).
> That's a modest speedup for a case that's already slow and we'd hope to avoid in general (note how slow it is even after, because we have to look in each of those packs for abbreviations). But it's a one-line change that clearly matches the original intent, so it seems worth doing.
>
> The included perf test may also be useful for keeping an eye on any regressions in the overall abbreviation code.

Comment: Adjusting your refspec will help reduce the number of objects transferred, but it doesn't reduce the initial ref advertisement done by the server--there's currently no way to reduce the latter.  Nonetheless, it's still a useful technique.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does.  Locally, it's not much of a problem--though it does still affect several local commands.  In particular, when you are trying to describe a commit based on the available refs.

Over the network, Git does an initial ref advertisement when you connect to it for updates.  You can learn about this in the [pack protocol](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/pack-protocol.html#_reference_discovery) document.  The problem here is that your network connection may be flaky or latent, and that initial advertisement can take a while as a result.  There has been discussions of removing this requirement, but, as always, compatibility issues make it complicated.  The most recent discussion about it is [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/git@vger.kernel.org/msg65701.html).

You probably want to look at a recent discussion about [Git scaling](http://www.mail-archive.com/git%40vger.kernel.org/msg65511.html) too.  There's many ways in which you may want Git to scale, and it's discussed the majority of them so far.  I think it gives you a good idea what Git is good at, and where it could use some work.  I'd summarize it for you, but I don't think I could do it justice.  There's a lot of useful information there.

Answer (score 3):

In order to answer your question, you should know how Git handle branches. What are branches?

A branch is only a *reference* to a commit to the local repo, creating branches is very cheap. `.git` directory contains directories that contains metadata that git uses, when you create a branch, what happens is that a reference is created to local branch and a history log is created. In other words, creating branches is creating files and references, the system can easily handle 2000 files.

I advise you to go through [3.1 Git Branching - Branches in a Nutshell](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell), it contains information that might help you to better undestand how branches are handled.

Answer (score 0):

i have a git repo with 200K branches and 5GB repo size... and its getting slow

im using git to store temporary files from web scraping. every file is a zip archive with about 20KB size on average. every day, i add 1000 new files, so the repo is about 200 days old now. the files are already compressed, so i have disabled delta compression with `* -delta` in `/.gitattributes` of every branch

to add a file, i create an orphan branch with

```bash
git worktree add --quiet --detach --no-checkout mnt
git -C mnt checkout --quiet --orphan files/12345
git -C mnt reset --quiet
git -C mnt clean -fdq --quiet
cp 12345.zip mnt/12345.zip
echo '* -delta' >mnt/.gitattributes
git -C mnt add --quiet .
git -C mnt commit --quiet -m "add 12345"
git worktree remove --quiet --force mnt
rm -rf mnt
```

in other words, i am using git as an append-only "blob storage" for a million small files. these files are immutable = they are never modified. maybe i could store these files as raw git blob objects, but then they have no filename

intentionally, i am not storing all files in the `main` branch, to make `git pull` and `git push --all` faster, and also to reduce the inode usage in the filesystem

but `git pull` and `git push --all` are getting slower and slower. currently `git push --all` takes 10...20 minutes to push 300 new branches at 100...150% cpu load = about 5...10KB/s "upload speed". i get the same speed when i push only some branches explicitly with `git push origin a b c d ...`. probably `git gc` is one reason for the slowdown

pushing one new branch (20KB) with `git push origin some_branch` takes about 30 to 60 seconds = about 0.5KB/s, `--force` does not make it faster

another problem is that git will create "a million files" in the `.git` folder, mostly in `.git/logs/refs/remotes/` and `.git/logs/refs/heads/`

with 200K branches, the github webinterface fails to render the `/branches` page, always showing a "unicorn error page"

i am not linking my repo here, because its a temporary repo, and i will delete it soon, because of the performance issues, and also because storing 5GB on github is not polite. 5GB is the "soft limit" on repo size, see also [Repository size limits for GitHub.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768454/repository-size-limits-for-github-com)

for long-term storage, im using sqlite databases, because sqlite gives the best read performance, compared to tar, 7z, squashfs, iso, udf, ... and because sqlite requires no root privileges to mount a filesystem like ext2, xfs, fat32, ... and because sqlite has native support in python, and because a database is generally more useful than a filesystem

note to myself: todo: monitor git performance over time. how exactly is the performance getting worse with an increasing number of branches? linear? logarithmic? quadratic?

see also [What are the file limits in Git (number and size)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984707/what-are-the-file-limits-in-git-number-and-size)