# Repository size limits for GitHub.com

Tags: git, github, repository, storage, limit

Lately I have been using GitHub and I am wondering what is the repository size limit for files hosted on github.com?

Comment: Similar question http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45254/file-size-and-storage-limits-on-github#84746

Answer (score 89, accepted):

From GitHub's [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/):

> GitHub doesn't have any set disk quotas. We try to provide abundant storage for all Git repositories, within reason. Keeping repositories small ensures that our servers are fast and downloads are quick for our users.

and

> In addition, we place a strict limit of files exceeding 100 MB in size.

Now for the non-canned part of my answer.  GitHub might allow you to store files up to 100MB, but you should also be vigilant to *not* version binary or other similar blob type files.  The reason for this is that Git doesn't handle binaries well, and storage can be a big penalty.  So if you find yourself pushing 100MB per file, you should check what type of file you are dealing with.

Answer (score 373):

### Known limits

There are multiple repo size limits which apply.

#### Soft limit

As of 2023, as per the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github#repository-size-limits), this is 5 GB. If you exceed this limit, is possible that you will receive an email from GitHub Support.

> We recommend repositories remain small, ideally less than 1 GB, and **less than 5 GB is strongly recommended**.

If you happen to receive a restricting email from GitHub Support for one or more public repos, please report it as a comment to this answer along with a link to the repos, including the circumstances surrounding it.

#### `git push` warning limits

As of 2020, the [archived docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20200521202931/https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/what-is-my-disk-quota) ([backup](https://archive.is/Hk9bo)) excerpted below stated the following. It is reasonably assumed that this still applies. This limit can obviously be ignored.

> If you reach 75GB, you'll receive a warning from Git in your terminal the next time you push a change.

Also, you'll receive a warning in the terminal for each file of over 50MB but under the hard limit.

#### Hard limits

As of 2023, although the [docs](https://nullreferer.com/?https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github#repository-size-limits) don't state the per repository hard limit, it is reasonably assumed that the previously documented **per repository hard limit of 100 GB** still applies, at least until any theoretical email from GitHub Support is received. The docs, also excerpted below, state only the **per file hard limit of 100 MB**.

> **Individual files in a repository are strictly limited to a 100 MB**
> maximum size limit.

As of 2020, the [archived docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20200521202931/https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/what-is-my-disk-quota) excerpted below stated that **the hard limit is 100 GB per repository**. Again, it is reasonably assumed that this hard limit still applies.

> **Repositories have a hard size limit of 100GB.**

As of 2018, the [documented](https://github.community/t/working-with-large-files-and-repositories/10203) [(archive link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025193224/https://github.community/t/working-with-large-files-and-repositories/10203) push size limit is 2 GB, although related [considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64565533/) also apply for large pushes.

> we don’t allow pushes over 2GB

Files can also be shared as binaries in a release. As of 2020, the [documented](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/distributing-large-binaries) size limit of each such file is 2 GB.

> We don't limit the total size of the binary files in the release or the bandwidth used to deliver them. However, each individual file must be smaller than 2 GB.

### Checking used size

The size of each repo to which you directly have Admin access, but not via a team, is shown at https://github.com/settings/repositories. Alternatively, the [git-sizer](https://github.com/github/git-sizer) tool can estimate the repo size locally.

### Bypassing the file size limit

Compression can obviously be used for some files if this puts them under the limit.

Large files can be split into smaller chunks. If it works for your application, a tool such as [`tar` plus `split`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61776/), or just [`split` alone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19031247/4561887), can be used to split a large file into smaller parts, such as 90 MB each.

Although [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) has separate quotas, it is however strictly advised to not use it, whether for binary or text files. This is due to the [meager limits](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/about-storage-and-bandwidth-usage) of its free plan as imposed by GitHub. If you made the mistake of using it, its [usage can be checked](https://docs.github.com/en/billing/managing-billing-for-git-large-file-storage/viewing-your-git-large-file-storage-usage) and [files can be removed](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/removing-files-from-git-large-file-storage) from it.

### Number of files

There is no established limit of the max number of files in a repo. A [post from 2015](https://www.monperrus.net/martin/one-million-files-on-git-and-github) notes having 1.7 million files in a GitHub repo. Note that having 1 million files would restrict each file to a maximum average of [5 KB](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%285+GB+%2F+1+million%29+in+KB) as per the soft limit of 5 GB or to [100 KB](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28100+GB+%2F+1+million%29+in+KB) as per the presumed hard limit of 100 GB.

### Number of commits

A user reported having a [repo disabled at 22 million commits](https://programming.dev/post/355447).

### How to write

To be able to successfully push a large number of bytes using git, it is highly likely that you'll first have to [configure `http.postBuffer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64565533/) to a sufficiently large value, with enough free system memory available.

Apart from using git, the other way to programmatically write files that are not updated much is to use the [v3 REST](https://docs.github.com/en/rest) or the [v4 GraphQL](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql) APIs using a [personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens). When doing so, ensure that the user-specific hourly rate limit is not exceeded. Unlike with git, this API doesn't however seem to allow submitting an increment or a diff.

### Encryption

It is possible to encrypt the contents of [the entire repo](https://superuser.com/a/1595398/) or just [some files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330742/) while using git, with several caveats.

### Comparison

For Bitbucket, consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73244577/). As feasible, I would personally [push to both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64513357/) GitHub and Bitbucket, providing an implicit backup.

As of 2022, GitLab (not GitHub) looks to be lowering its free quota from 10 GB per repo to a total of just [5 GB](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/usage_quotas.html) for all repos combined! You can see the total space used in your GitLab [account](https://gitlab.com/-/profile/usage_quotas#storage-quota-tab).

Comment: No sorry, as far as i know it's the only way to do it without opening git up. I know of it because it is regularly used in Unity and Unreal projects (them being binary most of the time). I should really mention that you shouldn't use glfs for all files since it uploads the entire file instead of only the changes.

Comment: Yes it can as it follows the same pattern matching as .gitignore https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format, You can setup this with the command line (link below for tutorial), or by adding your patterns to .gitattributes; example: https://gist.github.com/nemotoo/b8a1c3a0f1225bb9231979f389fd4f3f.
I highly recommend you look at the official site as well as the tutorial to get started https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial.

Comment: I do know of a repo which reached that limit, it's the opengapps repo, Here are the two articles that explains what happened after: 
https://opengapps.org/blog/post/2019/02/17/github-situation/
https://opengapps.org/blog/post/2019/08/23/sourceforge-migration/

Comment: I received this email from GitHub in May 2019 for a 5 GB fork (https://github.com/whosonfirst-data/whosonfirst-data/issues/1507) as did other forks and the upstream (https://whosonfirst.org/blog/2019/05/09/changes/). I deleted my fork, upstream split their 10+ GB? into smaller ones.

Comment: My fork wasn't high bandwidth. Only I had committed to it ([only 16 PRs' worth over 2 months](https://github.com/whosonfirst-data/whosonfirst-data/pulls?q=is%3Apr+sort%3Aupdated-desc+author%3Ahugovk+is%3Aclosed)), and it hadn't been updated in 3.5 years (Oct 2015-May 2019). Upstream was still active and busier.

Comment: I'd just like to confirm that the 100 MB file limit is still correct. I just got this error today during a `git push`: `remote: error: File cpp/floating_point_resolution/data/double_resolution_test_3_20201031#3.csv.tar.gz is 147.57 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB`.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Yes. That one is easy to test. I see you're using `gz` which typically has suboptimal compression. As I'm sure you know, you'll obviously have much better compression if using `xz`, `bzip2`, or `brotli`. With CSV I typically use `bzip2`.

Comment: You can also upload large binaries through github releases. No stated total limit or bandwidth limits though each binary is limited to 2GB. IIRC some projects with very high bandwidth usage received warnings. https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/distributing-large-binaries

Comment: @JaackoTorus GitHub LFS has such low free [limits](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/about-storage-and-bandwidth-usage) that it doesn't seem to make any sense to use it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi. The anchor (e.g. `#repository-size-limits` ) will be removed when visiting `https://nullrefer.com/?...` . Why not use the docs link directly?

Comment: @liki Thanks but it's not worth the excess attention to this answer from GitHub.

Comment: GitHub seems to have improved its [official documentation on large file size](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github) again in the last 6 months or so. I just [added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70427664/4561887) with the latest quotes. This answer above still contains correct info, but I've added some more quotes and summaries and mentioned GitHub's official `git sizer` tool to analyze one's repos.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Trivial changes, if any, aren't a good reason for a new answer, especially when there is so much to convey.

Comment: Do these size limits refer to the grand total git files (i.e., with all the history and commits of all branches) or only with the latest version or latest commit in the main branch?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira I am 99% sure they count something closer to the grand total, otherwise it would be a major vulnerability. I haven't confirmed it via a test, however.

Comment: Up until last night, I thought using `git lfs` was a good work-around to upload files > 100 MB into a public free GitHub repo. I no longer think that. [I just wrote about my reasons _against_ using `git lfs` now, here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75946411/4561887), for anyone wondering. The free usage of `git lfs` is really strict, and gets quickly used up when people even fork or clone your repo which uses `git lfs`.

Answer (score 17):

According to the 2019 version of this page ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20190501000000)) and https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/ there is not limit on the repo size, but after exceeding 1 GB they might email you and ask to reduce the size:

> We recommend repositories be kept under 1GB each. This limit is easy to stay within if large files are kept out of the repository. If your repository exceeds 1GB, you might receive a polite email from GitHub Support requesting that you reduce the size of the repository to bring it back down.

Additionally you will see warnings for pushing files bigger than 50 MB and files bigger than 100 MB won't be accepted.

Answer (score 4):

**File and repository size limitations**

To ensure good performance for our users, we recommend repositories be kept under 1GB each. Keeping repositories small ensures that our servers are fast and downloads are quick. If your repository does exceed 1GB, you might receive an email from GitHub Support asking you to reduce it.

Repositories have a hard size limit of 100GB. If you reach 75GB, you'll receive a warning from Git in your terminal the next time you push a change. In addition, we place a strict maximum size limit of 100 MB for individual files in a repository

Source: [Github -> what-is-my-disk-quota](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/what-is-my-disk-quota)

> **Note**: If you add a file to a repository via a browser, the file can be no larger than 25 MB. For more information

Answer (score 0):

Limits are increased.
This is 500Mb per file.
No limit for repository size.
Unlimited repositories.
These limits are for free accounts only.
If you pay limits really increase.

Anyway, if github fit your project, you shouldn't care much about limits, the real purpose of github, even since microsoft acquiered it is to get your source code.
Whatever you may think about that, they do provide interesting tools for teams and opensource codes. I would care much about hosting files on "somebody else computer" for compagny who really need security.

Comment: What is your source for this?

Comment: How are limits supposed to increase if the free version is already unlimited???