# Is there a limit of disk size for free github repository?

Tags: git, github, repository

The document in github seems not mentioned very clear, or I missed it:

1. `https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/`
2. `https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/`

Please help me.

Comment: Consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/59479166/832230

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that the repository disk size be kept under 1GB. Please view the following link for more details:

https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/