# Unable to git push even after git lfs install

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

Scenario 1:

- Tried to push file size > 100MB in github
- File > 100MB not allowed to push.Valid error. Agreed
- ok,use git lfs
- Still same error
- whats wrong here
- Below pics related to Scenario 1

Scenario 2:

- Cloned a new repo
- Created a new file > 100 MB
- Not yet pushed. I know it will be a problem
- do the git lfs install&track of big file and do git add&commit
- now if i git push, success, all ok . No issues. I can see the big file in github
- check it in https://github.com/sivakumar-j-secondary-ac/scenario-2

> so What's wrong in the "Scenario 1", if git lfs is working in scenario-2

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is a limit of Github. See it post https://stackoverflow.com/a/59479166/8019211

Comment: yes its a github limit. But we can overcome that with git lfs.. i am facing error when i use git lfs .. thats the reason of this question.. Note: I am able to use git lfs without issues.. see scenario 2 above

Comment: I have uploaded file > 100 mb in https://github.com/sivakumar-j-secondary-ac/scenario-2.. but before i pushed for first time.. i used git lfs...  scenario -2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to explicitly migrate them into Git LFS with

`git lfs migrate import --include="path_to_file`

instead of just tracking. Tracking does not work when files exist in the repository.

Hope this helps.