# Is there a limit to the Online Jupyter Notebook demo?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is there a limit in data storage here: https://jupyter.org/try?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Jupiter demo page that you referred to uses https://mybinder.org/ under the hood. In the FAQ section, they specify limits to the available RAM as 1GB - 2GB. However, they don't specify limits to storage space.

The reason for this is that the typical use case is to store all your data in a git repo, such as GitHub, so Binder uses a similar business model. GitHub also does not put limits on storage (see [Repository size limits for GitHub.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768454/repository-size-limits-for-github-com)). However, the larger your repo, the longer it will take to run your project, imposing a natural limit.

https://github.com/binder-examples/getting-data also provides some good insight regarding the various approaches to loading data into your mybinder docker container. Restricting network speed, blocking FTP and limiting traffic to sites like GitHub also limit how much data you can pull into your docker container.

At the end of the day, the storage limits are based on respect. Don't abuse the platform.