# git push: fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly Connection to github.com closed by remote host

Tags: git, github, ssh, push

I'm using ssh and RSA keys to access github, but it doesn't work when I push files to the repository.

```
somename54@THISPC:~/repos/homework-1-name54$ git push
Enumerating objects: 6, done.
Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 2.79 KiB | 2.79 MiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: looks like you had a network issue, did you retry ?

Comment: Yes, @CyrilJouve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that the this error usually happens when your files are too big. But my files were not, and I was able to push all of my other projects. Re-cloning into a separate directory helped, but it did not fix the original issue.

Comment: another helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59479166/2368696) to know github limitation

Answer (score 4):

You can use this question as a reference: [Git, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/)

- some users face this problem comes due to the buffer settings: e.g. `git config ssh.postBuffer 524288000`
- you may have misconfigured you remote in the repo (you can check with `git remote -v`) or the ssh keypair

  - you can to remove the ssh origin and replace it with http
  - you may forgot to add your ssh key to your agent (`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`)
  - you can re-run the steps described in the github documentation https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent
- in other cases, running the garbage collector fixed the issue (`git gc`)
- you may have missing writing permissions if you created the repository as root (sudo) and git is installed for your user

Comment: `git config ssh.postBuffer 524288000` made it for me.

Comment: Uh, I don't think `ssh.postBuffer` is a config setting. Maybe you're thinking of https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httppostBuffer

Comment: Found these answers and tried `ssh.postBuffer` first but I didn't think it worked for me. In my case the error happened when git was "compressing objects". So I tried `git gc`, which significantly reduced the number of objects git had to compress. After than `git push` went through, although it still took a while.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue when trying to push a commit, but I was able to push and pull from my other branches. When I tried again to push on the branch that was having the issue, it was successful.