# Git push: fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git

I'm encountering a problem in my project when I'm trying to push my project to **GIT**, I tried every solution on the Internet nothing works for me. I am getting this error:

```
PS C:\Users\burac\Desktop\AppsPro\myapp> git push
Enumerating objects: 11468, done.
Counting objects: 100% (10767/10767), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4713/4713), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (10062/10062), 2.37 GiB | 4.36 MiB/s, done.
Total 10062 (delta 5638), reused 9585 (delta 5179), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/63695221/10970871

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git push: fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly Connection to github.com closed by remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63695221/git-push-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-connection-to-github-com-cl)

Comment: `2.37 GiB` is rather large and exceeds the allowed size on multiple hosting sites: what hosting site are you using?

Comment: I tried all the fixes :( nothing works ....
Changed my gitconfig limits still the same error: 

[core]
 editor = \"C:\\Users\\burac\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" --wait
 packedGitLimit = 1024m
 packedGitWindowSize = 1024m
 #compression = 0
[filter "lfs"]
 clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
 smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
 process = git-lfs filter-process
 required = true
[http]
 postBuffer = 524288000

[pack] 
 deltaCacheSize = 2047m
 packSizeLimit = 4095m
 windowMemory = 4095m
 windowsMemory = 4095m