# GitHub desktop upload limit

Tags: git, github, version-control

It’s a pretty simple question, say that I wanna upload a lot of files to a Git local repo and then push it to a remote one on GitHub. I want to use the [github desktop app](https://desktop.github.com/), the upload might take a while so before trying to do anything I wanted to know: is there a limit for the size you commit to the local repository and the one you push to the remote one?

So maybe if the limit is too small for me I wont lose time waiting for it to upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub Desktop itself does not hold any included limit as far as I can tell. 
It basically is just a front-end client for Git and GitHub itself.

GitHub however does have file limits:

- Individual files have a size limit of 100mb each.
- Repositories do not have file size limits, but they a recommended to be under 1GB and definitely under 5GB.
- 1 push cannot contain more than 2GB worth of data
- GitHub Desktop may warn you if your repository reaches a certain point, as the Git CLI warns you in the terminal if your repository exceeds 75GB

For more detail explanation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59479166/9178557)

If you have large files which do need versioning in GitHub, maybe look into [GitHub Large File Storage](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-git-large-file-storage)