# speed up git clone when remote have so many branches

Tags: git, branch

We have a git repo that have more than 30 thousands branches.

When i run `time git clone http://<gerrit-host>/manifest.git`, it stop at `Cloning into 'manifest'...` for about 1 minutes and 20 seconds, and this command totally cost 1m45s.

For my purpose, **I only want to download `branch_ci`** which has only one file of `default.xml`. So I try:

`time git clone -b branch_ci --single-branch --depth 1 http://<gerrit-host>/manifest.git`

the total cost is still 1m18s.

**I know if I clone full repo from remote, it definitely should be slow. But I think If I only clone one branch which have only one file and little commits, shouldn't it be much faster?**

How can I improve the performance of only one branch clone if remote has so many branches? Or this is the branch implementation of git that lead to this bad performance.

I've already checked this [Impact of large number of branches in a git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849302/impact-of-large-number-of-branches-in-a-git-repo), but not get any idea.

Comment: What is your use case? Pipeline, local develop clone, other?

Comment: @Kim I'm trying to improve cicd performance and hoping to find some clue. I've edit the question for a clarify.

Comment: You could try experimenting with a treeless clone instead I guess. https://github.blog/2020-12-21-get-up-to-speed-with-partial-clone-and-shallow-clone/
Also look into if there is any way to not do fresh clone each time ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: For cicd clones, you can also try [--reference](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---reference-if-ableltrepositorygt).

Comment: Whether or not cloning one branch will save you much time compared to all branches, is highly dependent on the content of those branches. If the reason the repo has so many branches is because nobody deletes their branches after completing a PR, then most of the branches would be fully merged and are pointless bookmarks that take up no additional object space. In that case not cloning those branches saves you nothing. Surely there are some branches with unmerged commits on them, and perhaps some of them have largish files or changes, and that's where the only savings would come in.

Comment: In Bash, compare `git rev-list origin/main | wc` (or whatever your single branch is) with `git rev-list --all | wc` to see how many commits are in the repo that aren't on your single branch.

Comment: @TTT `git rev-list origin/main | wc` output `15      15     615`, `git rev-list --all | wc` output `61392   61392 2517072`

Comment: 15 commits on `origin/main` seems low for your branch. Looks like I should have said `git rev-list origin/branch_ci | wc` since that's the branch you actually care about. (I'm guessing "origin" is the remote name, but if you already have a local clone with that branch checked out you could use `branch_ci` too.)

Comment: @TTT sorry, i mean `git rev-list origin/branch_ci | wc` output `15      15     615`. Actually `manifest` repo is android multi reository management.  The  branches in `manifest` repo are not traditional branches, they are all totally different like a new repo, each branch represents a product. I'll study this topic later for now have other work to do.

Comment: Based on 15 commits compared to 61K, one would think the 15 commits would be **much** smaller based on size alone. But maybe you have some huge objects in the commits on your branch, and perhaps it's actually your branch that is the bulk of the entire repo size. (Or a shared initial commit.) The next thing to check is the output of the clone command- it tells you the size of the download. Also, compare the size of your freshly cloned `.git` folder, both after cloning just your branch vs cloning the entire repo. If it's still sizeable even with just those 15 commits, then you have your answer.