# Maximum size of Gerrit project/repository

Tags: git, gerrit

I am planning to `migrate project to gerrit`. The size of the project is `10GB` and there is `scope for increase` in size.

Can Gerrit handle such huge projects?

Comment: Gerrit wouldn’t really care about the size of the actual repository or its files. If working with that project works fine with Git, then Gerrit will likely work fine too. It’s more the size of Gerrit’s data itself that may have an impact later but that depends on how much activity your repository is getting.

Comment: @poke. Thank you for the response. Any idea on limitation of size in Git.

Comment: See [this answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/984973/216074) for that. In general, there is no real limit. It depends a lot on where that repository size comes from; Is it individual file objects being very large? Or is it that the history is that large that Git has so many objects created that it takes 10GB? The former is no problem, the latter might become one at some point. A good idea is to compare your project to the Linux kernel project which is kind of the best example for a huge Git project.

Comment: @poke. Thanks. The history is not large. The individual files are large. Do you have any links for Linux kernel project to refer

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit can handle a 10GB repository but I think it's good to track the Gerrit performance continually. See more info about Gerrit scaling [here](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/homepage/+/md-pages/docs/Scaling.md).