# How much history can be migrated from SVN to GIT repository

Tags: git, svn

I'm looking at migrating our huge SVN repository code base to GIT.
Needed some idea on how much of SVN's history(in terms of years or size) can be moved to git.   What is the GIT history capacity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the file limits in Git (number and size)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984707/what-are-the-file-limits-in-git-number-and-size)

Comment: Just for comparison: [The largest Git repo on the planet](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/05/24/the-largest-git-repo-on-the-planet/). 3.5M files, … a repo of about 300GB … about 4,000 engineers and the engineering system produces 1,760 daily “lab builds” across 440 branches…

Comment: ASF SVN repo: 1827482 revisions. See http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ and https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#asf

Answer (score 2):

Git's Achilles heel is large binary files. As long as you have mostly non-binary files (text files), it will handle a large number of commits and files.

A good reference is the Linux project with over 700,000 commits.