# Git Repository Size

Tags: git

we would like to know what will be maximum size of Git Repository.Are there any standard to follow  this.As per my knowledge Git is good for source type of file system.we would like to know is it good for holding packages for any derived object(output of build) or binary repo.

Thanks
DJM

Comment: You can use it to save binaries, for sure... but it's not optimized for doing so.

Comment: Thanks i see many company use this for project which is have video/audio and multimedia type of files also will not this increase in the size of repo so would like to hear exactly what we should have size

Comment: There is not a fixed hard limit on repository size, other than any imposed by your particular computer. There *was* a 4 gigabyte limit on pack files in much older versions of Git but this has been removed. (Well, technically there's a maximum size of 2^63-1, but you'll hit your own computer's limits way before this.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the file limits in Git (number and size)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984707/what-are-the-file-limits-in-git-number-and-size)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+store+huge+binaries

Comment: thanks for this but still will not be problem if suppose i have repo of around 20GB so every time if user do clone he/she need to do clone of 20GB