# Clearcase authentication

Tags: clearcase

I am planning to setup Clearcase for version control in our project, but I am new to Clearcase and has few very basic questions about it.

Some background: we are using Windows platform

1. Is it possible to install Clearcase server (the VOBS server) in Windows XP?
2. How do Clearcase authenticate user? Can I logon to my Clearcase client with local account instead of domains account?

Comment: If you are new to ClearCase, consider also reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074580/clearcase-advantages-disadvantages and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923328/what-are-the-differences-between-a-snapshot-view-and-a-dynamic-view

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can. See this ["System Requirement" page for ClearCase 7.1.x](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21302974): Windows Xp (SP2 and SP3) is still supported.
2. ClearCase will use the login of your current session as credential, and whatever group you will have declared in the `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` environment variable:
   See the "[about `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` variable](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21135509)" technote (if not set, your [group will default to "Domain Users"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21147322)).

See this [technote for more about permission for a Windows environment](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21143292) with ClearCase object: the [`creds.exe` utility](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21221403) is useful to check one's credential as detected and used by ClearCase.

Comment: I checked the System Requirement page, but it has a footnote like this: "Microsoft Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7 hosts are supported as ClearCase clients. ClearCase servers in the context of this statement refer to VOB servers. You can store views on a Client"

So does it mean that XP can only be used as Clearcase client, but not server?

Comment: @ArthasTsang: no you can install ClearCase server as well on Xp. View server (part of the client features, and Vob server, part of the "server" features)

Comment: Seems Clearcase is very complicated with lots of terminology. Maybe I try to describe what I want to do and see if it is possible. First I want to install the Clearcase server on an XP machine, create a Clearcase user group for access control, and share the Clearcase repository over the network. Each developer will be working on their own XP client, logon to the Windows with local account, and then provide the Clearcase group credential when they want to access the repository on server.

Comment: @ArthasTsang: if the group and login exists both on the server and the client (with the same name, not necessarily the same id), it will work.

Comment: I have installed Clearcase server and client on two XP machine(both machine doesn't belong to any NT domain), and logged on with local user. But when I run the Clearcase Doctor, it alert me the following problems: 1. Reconfigure local account to Windows NT domain 2. User not logged on to a Windows NT domain account 3. Computer not on NT domain. Are these just warnings? Or I must use Windows domain?

Comment: @ArthasTsang for evaluation purpose, you could try and ignore those, but a Windows domain is still needed for ClearCase right management: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/domain-admin.htm

Answer (score 0):

Possible if you expect users to log on locally...if your going for an enterprise setup,
you should explore the server & domain setup such that you can take advantage of ClearCase's
distributed architecture and all the benefits...having said that :)

Yes its possible (maybe you want to test/experiment/toy with it..)

you will need to create:

1. clearcase_albd account (clearcase system account)
2. A ClearCase local group (clearcase_albd as member)
3. A clearusr local group (normal user group)

During install you will be asked for these values...

Note post install ClearCase doctor will nag you with the fact that its not on a domain...can ignore

But it will work.

Good luck
Jim2