# ClearCase not working via Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, clearcase

*Intellij Idea 12.1.4, Windows 7 Professional.*

It seems bundled ClearCase Intellij Idea plugin not working at all. When I try to checkout(or type sth. in a file which is not checked out or hijacked) Idea says:

```
Cannot edit file(s): cleartool: Error: Not an object in a vob: {File path}
```

Actually this is an error that I am expecting because I couldn't find any ClearCase configuration that I can type my user name and password in Intellij Idea:

[image]

That's why it doesn't know where to connect and retrieve data. So question is, where are the correct configurations? Should I prepare a script for SCR text file or is Intellij Idea plugin useless?

Answer (score 1):

Try first to fall back to cleartool (the ClearCase CLI -- command Line Interface), and check if your view is correctly configured.

```
cd /path/to/your/file
cleartool ls
```

That will allow you to see the config spec selection rule for that file.
And that will give you a clue for that  "Not an object in a vob" error message: maybe the issue isn't in the plugin, but in your current view.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your answer, probably you guessed right. I was using ClearCase via Eclipse and there was not any problem with that same view. Also I have only ClearCase Remote Client but don't have external CLI program however from windows command line when I go to project's main folder(cd command) and type cleartool ls it says: `Error: Pathname is not within a VOB: "."`

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı which version of ClearCase are you using? a CTE (clearTeam Explorer) 8.x? If you can type `cleartool`, then this isn't CCRC. And you should type `cleartool ls` in the parent directory of the file you are trying to check out.

Comment: `Help> About: Rational ClearCase Remote Client Version: 7.1.2`. Also I'have tried to type ls command in the parent of that file, but same result: `Error: Pathname is not within a VOB: "."`

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı can you share the full path of that folder (C:\..; or M:\...)?. You do have a full ClearCase, not CCRC. Can you also share the result of a (in that same folder): `cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview`?

Comment: Folder: `C:\msfa\msfa_view\TEA_Revised\CustomerManagement\SFA\TMSFA\MobileSFA\src\com\tur
kcell\mobile\sfa\bean` And the result of `cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview` :
cleartool: Error: Cannot get view info for current view: not a ClearCase object.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı so something seem to be wrong with your snapshot view. I supposed your view is in `C:\msfa\msfa_view`, and the Vob is named `\TEA_Revised`, correct? Try to execute the `lsview` in `C:\msfa\msfa_view`. One of the folders within that view must be in an incorrect state.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı But this also illustrates that the issue isn't with the IntelliJ plugin (at least for now).

Comment: `lsview` listed millions of files. How can i detect the anomaly? But if there is an error why can i use remote client or Eclipse plugin correctly?

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı I meant: the command I reference earlier: `cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview`

Comment: That gives: `Error cannot get view info for current view: not a ClearCase object.`

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı strange: the all view doesn't seem to be recognized by ClearCase. I would try and make a *second* snapshot view, and see if the `cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview` works better there, then test the IntilliJ plugin.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı the idea remains: as long as basic `cleartool` commands don't work, it is too soon to debut the IntelliJ plugin.

Comment: Even though creating a new view and trying `cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview` sounds rational it still gives `Error cannot get view info for current view: not a ClearCase object`. I have created new view that named as `msfa_view_ij` then executed cd `C:\msfa\msfa_view_ij` then `cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview`.  I guess I am facing with totally exceptional case.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı or something is wrong with the ClearCase services. What does the logs are saying? (type `clearhomebase`, tab "Administration", button "ClearCase Host Administration", or just type `cchostadmin.msc`. Look in all the server logs of your Clearcase host (your computer) to see if there are any clues there.

Comment: That gives an error about permissions because vob located in a server machine which doesn't gives me admin permissions.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı Then you need to find an admin who will be able to have a look at the log (even the logs from your computer, accessed remotely).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a contrite answer but the best advice really is: Don't use ClearCase.

Save your organization the headache and make the effort to switch over.

Anything will do, even svn.

Comment: I would agree with that ;) I compare [ClearCase and Git here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/645771/6309), and details [ClearCase linmits there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1074785/6309)

Comment: I agree so much that however this is the tool that big boss likes :( but thanks for advice. and @VonC thanks for helping and kind answers, I am going to investigate logs after deadline, till that time I am privately with Remote Client :(

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı I'm sorry to hear that the tool is prescribed. My experience in such circumstances is to keep a time log of all the time that is "wasted" chasing up clearcase admins or solving clearcase problems. If you can demonstrate what a time sink it is and propose a viable alternative your boss may give in!

Comment: Wow, we got a downvote! I guess the single remaining ClearCase user in the world dropped by and downvoted this answer... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings, click on "Version Control". In the right-hand pane you need to add a Directory/VCS configuration tuple. Do this by pressing the green PLUS (+) icon.

Select "Project" and select "Clearcase" as Source Control tool. You should now have a context menu item "Clearcase" in your IDE and can check out files by right-clicking on the file. One small disadvantage in my Intellij 12.1.6 is that he only sees the change sets (Activities) that were created using Clearcase Explorer... (only loaded at startup time of Intellij). So you cannot add new change sets that will be propagated to Clearcase.