# Examples of how to visualize a versioning system?

Tags: version-control, project-management, versioning, visualization, release-management

My shop is trying to formalize the release management process for an OSS product we maintain (edit: using SVN for version control). It's a sort of a web development framework/CMS kind of thing, as in it's a product that other projects are built on top of. This makes clear communication about the versioning system especially critical for developers that are using the tool.

I'm hoping to find some examples of how best to graph this system so we can communicate it better internally and with outside developers. I know there are lots of standards and best practices around versioning, so I'm hoping this extends to some sort of visual vocabulary as well. As one example, there is a nifty graph at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning#Software_Versioning_schemes. Are there any guides out there on how these sorts of things should be designed?

Answer (score 3):

First, if it is an OSS project, chances are the versioning system ism a [Distributed one (**DVCS**)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704996/describe-your-workflow-of-using-version-control-vcs-or-dvcs/2705286#2705286)

If so, then this [branching model can be of interest](http://nvie.com/git-model).
The idea is to control what you want to integrate from remote repos.

[alt text http://nvie.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/Screen-shot-2009-12-24-at-11.32.03.png](http://nvie.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/Screen-shot-2009-12-24-at-11.32.03.png)

Comment: This is a great chart, but the project is using Subversion for right now. I'm a big fan of how Github does these charts and would love to find a similar tool for SVN.

Answer (score 0):

I need this too. The built-in graph in Tortoise SVN is too busy, but I've made use of it. But for soemthing like VonC's picture above, I think I'm going to go with a dry erase board and colored markers. I'll hang it outside my cube. Annotate it with revs, dates, sprints and projects, and we'll be all set.