# egit plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, egit, gitlab

I have created a gitlab repository and followed the installation instruction by the letter and it was successful (i think... i can browse the repository online) and now I want to connect the egit plugin from eclipse to this remote repository.

I was using SVN for quite some time and now we need to switch to git and I am confused. egit only gives me the option to create a local repository but I'm  a bit lost on how to push/fetch code to my online repository.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: First you need to clone the remote repository

Answer (score 2):

With Gitlab (working with ssh urls), that means you have to register your public and private ssh key in Egit first before being able to clone it.

See [EGit ssh configuration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration)

[image: EGit ssh config]

Then you can [clone it](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote#Cloning_remote_Repositories).

And yes, you need to clone the full repo locally to work on it, that is the difference between a:

- CVCS (Centralized Version Control System) like SVN
- DVCS: *Distributed* Version Control System.

See "[Sell me Distributed revision control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563836/sell-me-distributed-revision-control/2563917#2563917)" and  "[Describe your workflow of using version control (VCS or DVCS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704996/describe-your-workflow-of-using-version-control-vcs-or-dvcs?lq=1)" for more.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to clone the remote repository using `git clone <repository>`, then you can import it to eclipse using egit

Or

You can use the clone functionality provided by EGit to clone the remote repo to local system

Comment: so you always have to clone your gitlab repository to a local one? Because when I was using SVN that was not the case. Only one repository was maintained... and that was the remote one

Comment: Yes, with git you never work directly on the remote repository, you always clone the repo locally make changes, commit changes and then push the changes back to the remote repo