# Bitnami: How to configure GitLab 5.0 application in Apache2 not to have relative root?

Tags: path, gitlab, apache2, relative-path, bitnami

(Or how to make GitLab application as root application on Apache2 HTTP server. )

I have not used Apache2 before, but I got [Bitnami GitLab VM](http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab/virtual-machine) with preinstalled server.

I and run into issues, because application root is relative.
[Bitnami GitLab 5.0 and git & Eclipse EGit quick start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757642/bitnami-gitlab-5-0-and-git-eclipse-egit-quick-start)

The fix is to not using relative root, but run GitLab application as root on Apache2 HTTP server.

I have found configuration files location using [Bitnami wiki for Apache component](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache?highlight=apache):

1) `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` is absent.

2) Apache2 config for GitLab aplication: `gitlab.conf`

[image: gitlab.conf]

Please help:

**How to configure GitLab 5.0 application in Apache2 not to have relative root?**

UPDATE: This is still unsolved, my own answer doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Have you precompiled the assets again? To do so, you should run:

```
$ cd /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs
$ bundle exec bin/rake assets:precompile RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT='/'
```

Then restart Apache server.

More info: http://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_GitLab#How_to_change_the_default_URL_to_the_root.3f

I hope it helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

[Bitnami wiki for Apache component - How to change the URL?](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache?highlight=apache#How_to_change_the_URL.3f)

2) way

> If you want to change the default URL from
>   `http://your_domain/your_application` to `http://your_domain`, you should
>   add a "DocumentRoot" entry in your application conf file. Edit the
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/your_application/conf/your_application.conf file to
>   add this line and commenting the "Alias" entries. You can use the
>   "nano" editor:
>
> `$ sudo nano /opt/bitnami/apps/your_application/conf/your_application.conf`
>
> your_application.conf file content:

```
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/your_application/htdocs"
# Alias /your_application/ "/installdir/apps/your_application/htdocs/"
# Alias /your_application "/installdir/apps/your_application/htdocs"

(...)
```

> Some applications also require changes in their configuration files or
>   in the database.

`/opt/bitnmai/apps/gitlab/gitlab.conf` after changes:

```
DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs/public

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs/public">
   Options -MultiViews
   allow from all
</Directory>

PassengerDefaultUser git
PassengerDefaultGroup git

PassengerPreStart htttp://127.0.0.1:80/
```

[image]

See also http://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_GitLab#How_to_change_the_default_URL_to_the_root.3f

Comment: This however had some bug with icons with GitLab 5.0

Answer (score 1):

[BitNami GitLab](http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab) 6.0 has been released and it is configured in the root URL by default.

Comment: That is nice How to update? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478029/how-to-update-gitlab-in-bitnami-stack?rq=1 The standard GitLab procedure doesn't apply (as back-up procedure too)