# Bitnami: Impossible to install Nginx on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, bitnami, gitlab

I am not Ubuntu guru, and wanted quick start wit [GitLab](http://gitlab.org/).
After getting [Bitnami GitLab VM](http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab), I ran into [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757642/bitnami-gitlab-5-0-and-git-eclipse-egit-quick-start), and [can't configure Apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900937/bitnami-how-to-configure-gitlab-5-0-application-in-apache2-not-to-have-relative).

Now want to follow [GitLab 5.0 installation](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/5-0-stable/doc/install/installation.md#7-nginx), and install Nginx. However running

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

returns:

> Package nginx is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>
> Thy may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source.

Please help what should I do next.

UPDATE: List of component is in [README.txt](http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab/README.txt)
[New version of stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab/changelog.txt) is mentioned, but not yet available for download:
Version: 5.0.1-0      2013-04-10 -> I am going to try.

Comment: But the Bitnami base stack already include an NGinX: http://wiki.bitnami.com/BitNami_Cloud_Hosting/Base_stack

Comment: Yes, Nginx is base component. But not all base components are included into every VM.

Comment: In the Ubuntu servers launched from BitNami Cloud Hosting include all the base components. However the BitNami GitLab VM is configured with Apache and nginx is not included. could you execute 'apt-get update' to update the packages list and try again to install nginx from the repository?

Comment: apt-get update was answering with some errors.
I will not continue with installing Nginx, as I will try Bitnami Gitlab Version: 5.1.0-3  from 2013-05-08
However, it is open question, if it is possible install Nginx on Bitnami stack