# How to update GitLab in Bitnami stack

Tags: updating, bitnami, gitlab

I am trying [BitNami GitLab Stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab/virtual-machine) 5.1.0-2,
and while I was doing that [5.1.0-3](http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab/README.txt) was released.

How to update GitLab in Bitnami stack?

Related to
[BitNami GitLab Stack 5.1.0-2 with LDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413490/bitnami-gitlab-stack-5-1-0-2-with-ldap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/master/doc/update

This how to's explains about upgrading the gitlab. But there are certain concerns.

Gitlab can be upgraded but gitlab-shell throws an error as "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git" which I guess needs answers from "Bitnami" or from Guru's.

So, be cautious.

Comment: Just tried section 7 from update that is common for all versions. In Bitnami it doesn't show green   
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production
 -> rake aborted! as
`<top (required)>` seen as wrong token