# BitNami GitLab Stack 5.1.0-2 with LDAP

Tags: git, configuration, ldap, bitnami, gitlab

I am [configuring](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md#ldap-authentication) LDAP for [BitNami GitLab Stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab/virtual-machine) [5.1.0-2](http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab/README.txt)

I use following settings for `/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs/config/gitlab.yml`

```
  ## LDAP settings
  ldap:
    enabled: true
    host: '192.168.1.14'
    base: 'DC=company,DC=com'
    port: 389
    uid: 'sAMAccountName'
    method: "plain"
    bind_dn: 'gitlab-ldap@company.com'
```

Example at GitHub https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/gitlab.yml.example#L82-L91

After restart I see <kbd>LDAP Sign in</kbd> as default button, but I can't login.

> Could not authorize you from Ldap because "Network is unreachable
>   - connect(2)

Where to find GitLab log? How to solve this?

Previous attempt was [Bitnami GitLab 5.0 and git & Eclipse EGit quick start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757642/bitnami-gitlab-5-0-and-git-eclipse-egit-quick-start)

UPDATE. Server is virtual machine having static IP, and domain name `gitlab.company.com`.
Gitlab is configured to use gitlab.funshion.com as IP name. See [Bitnami FAQ](http://bitnami.com/faq/virtual_machines)

$ sudo /opt/bitnami/updateip --machine_hostname gitlab.funshion.com

Even so `gitlab.company.com/gitlab` is application URL.

UPDATE 2:
logs are under `/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs/log/`
application.log - created project, etc, high level stuff
gitlabini.log - end with Administrator account created: ... 
NOTEMPTY
production.log  - that is it!
sidekiq.log

production.log
[image: production.log]

UPDATE 3： After restart I got

> Could not authorize you from Ldap because “Server 192.168.133.100
>   refused connection on port 389”.

But 192.168.133.100 is actually my `http://gitlab.company.com/` server

See [BitNami GitLab Stack 5.1.0-2 rewrites gitlab.yml after reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539993/bitnami-gitlab-stack-5-1-0-2-rewrites-gitlab-yml-after-reboot)

UPDATE 4: The same problem with GitLab 5.4
I have found article "Gitlab Active Directory LDAP Authentication" https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Gitlab_and_Active_Directory_LDAP_Authentication.html, but all attempts with word letter case did not succed.

Comment: do you see any '`log`' directory anywhere? The `Gitlab::Logger` class mentions (github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/lib/gitlab/logger.rb): `Rails.root`.

Comment: did you find the solution already. i'm in the same spot as you? where to look up?