# Difference in GIT betw. branch, clone and snapshot

Tags: git, branch, clone, snapshot

How are these action different?
- to branch
- to clone
- to take a snapshot

They all copy a set of files from one directory to another.

Comment: The [documentation](http://git-scm.com/documentation) is your friend :)

Answer (score 1):

- "to clone" is done by [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) and copies over to your local storage the *all* history of a repository (with *all* its branches)
- "to branch" is done by [git branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) (or [`git checkout -b aNewBranch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)) in your local repo, and add a local branch (that you would need to push if you wish to publish it, or that you can keep local and merge into another branch later)
- "to take a snapshot" is done by [`git tag`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) and add to a commit a tag (again a local operation: you can push a tag to an **[upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)** or keep it in your local repo only)

See also "[DVCS workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2705286/6309)".