# How can I merge local site with a staging remote

Tags: wordpress, git, git-merge

My origin/master is bitbucket and I have a staging site on WP Engine.  I want to merge my local site with the staging site.  I am not sure what to do next.  I fetched the staging site, but not sure if that is right and what I should do next.

Comment: It seems you're stuck at a pretty basic step. I recommend reading (or re-reading) the relevant sections (working with branches, working with remotes), of the completely free git book http://git-scm.com/book and come back with more specific questions.

Comment: Have you done at git branch -a to list all of your branches?  or git branch -r to list all remotes?

Answer (score 0):

> I fetched the staging site, but not sure if that is right

It is essentially how a **[*distributed* workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2705286/6309)** works (as illustrated in this [blog post](http://logoscreative.co/my-wordpress-development-process/)): you do work *locally*, and then push back.

That means that you fetch your staging site, and then merge (for instance, supposing you did call the staging site 'staging' as a remote) `staging/master` into your own `master`.
Once the merge is done and is working as you want, you can push back to `origin` (your bitbucket repo), and deploy from there (the deploy mechanism depends on your current setup, maybe you have [BitBucket hook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Bitbucket+hooks), like a [POST hook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/POST+hook+management))