# Need help to understand merge conflict example

Tags: git, merge

I am following an example from a book which does not show the step to resolve a merge conflict. The tutorial which teaches that did not work for me as mentioned in this post - [Simulate multiple users/committer's on local system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094185/simulate-multiple-users-committers-on-local-system)
So, I could not even learn the merge.

Here are the steps copied from the book -

Now open the  blank `participants.txt` file and paste the following lines in it:
(**I added a hyphen before each name**)

```
Finance team
 Charles
 Lisa
 John
 Stacy
 Alexander
```

Git code -

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial list for finance team'
```

Create a new branch called  marketing using the following syntax:

```
git checkout -b marketing
```

Now open the `participants.txt` file and start entering the names for the marketing department below the finance team list, as follows:
(**I added a hyphen before each name**)

```
Marketing team
 Collins
 Linda
 Patricia
 Morgan
```

Git code -

```
git add .
git commit -m 'Unfinished list of marketing team'
git checkout master
```

Open the file and delete the names Alexander and Stacy, save, close, add the changes, and commit
with the commit message  Final list from Finance team .

```
git add .
git commit -m "Final list from Finance team"
git checkout marketing
```

Open the file and add the fifth name, Amanda, for the marketing team, save, add, and commit.

```
git add .
git commit -m "Initial list of marketing team"
```

Say the same names entered for marketing have been confirmed; now we need to merge these two lists, which can be done by the following command.

```
git merge master
```

You will get a merge conflict as shown in the following screenshot. Resolve them.

```
Auto-merging participants.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in participants.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

**How do I resolve those conflicts ?**

The text in the file is as follows -

```
Finance team
-Charles
-Lisa
-John
<<<<<<< HEAD
-Stacy
-Alexander

Marketing team
- Collins
- Linda
- Patricia
- Morgan
- Amanda
=======
>>>>>>> master
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those are merge markers:

```
<<<<<<<
Changes made on the branch that is being merged into. In most cases,
this is the branch that I have currently checked out (i.e. HEAD).
|||||||
The common ancestor version.
=======
Changes made on the branch that is being merged in. This is often a 
feature/topic branch.
>>>>>>>
```

As explained in "[Fix merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7589612/6309)", you are supposed to:

- remove them
- keep the lines you want to see in the final version of the file
- add and commit

Or you can simply checkout those file to keep the original version, as in "[How can I discard remote changes and mark a file as “resolved”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2073854/6309)".

As you can see, the name you have deleted from the `Finance Team` in `marketing` branch (`Stacy` and `Alexander`) are back.
So when you are merging `master` into `marketing`, git is asking you: decide, should we keep those names or removes them?

---

As [Charles Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19563/charles-bailey) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103490/need-help-to-understand-merge-conflict-example/24103709?noredirect=1#comment37181511_24103709), it seems the (base) common ancestor section is missing:

```
|||||||
The common ancestor version.
=======
```

you should redo the exercice with the config:

```
git config merge.conflictStyle  diff3
```

That will help visualize the base section  of the [3-way merging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28revision_control%29#Three-way_merge).
See also "[Why is a 3-way merge advantageous over a 2-way merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4130766/6309)".

---

The OP [adds](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5008405)

> After you decide what to keep in the text file and remove the merge markers, `<<<HEAD` and `>>>master`, you need to add the files to the stage with `git add [filename]`, then commit as normal.
>   You cannot just execute `git merge master` right away.

When merging again, the OP reports the error message:

```
error: 'merge' is not possible because you have unmerged files. 
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, 
hint: and then use 'git add/rm <file>' as 
hint: appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit, 
hint: or use 'git commit -a'. 

fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

> Here is the solution

```
git add .
git commit - m "success"
git merge master
```

See "[GIT merge error “commit is not possible because you have unmerged files”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12961752/6309)".

Comment: You might want to mention the "merge.conflictStyle = diff3" configuration option seeing as the conflict style in the question lacks the [really important] common base section.

Comment: Thank again VonC. I have some questions. Could you please answer them for me ? What is this git master ? Is it the original text/code or another branch like marketing ? Thanks.

Comment: @sidsmith master is the name of the default branch present in all git repo. See http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging or https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/git-branches#!branch, but also the excellent tutorial http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/.

Comment: @sidsmith but regarding the basic concepts of git, the best introduction is at https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

Comment: @sidsmith sure, but the interactive and visual tutorial of http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/ is quite effective too.

Comment: @CharlesBailey thank you for pointing that out. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @VonC - oh I meant pcottle link. Btw, as per old chapter in my book, the `<<<<HEAD` is the current position in the repository. How can that be ? My current position is `marketing` branch which has all five names present in original finance list.

Comment: @sidsmith `HEAD` refers in your case to the `marketing` branch. To better understand what `HEAD` is, read the first two answer of http://stackoverflow.com/q/964876/6309.

Comment: Great, when I enter `git merge master` I get the error `
error: 'merge' is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree,
hint: and then use 'git add/rm <file>' as
hint: appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit,
hint: or use 'git commit -a'.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.`

Comment: @sidsmith sure, you should merge again if you have a merge in progress. The error message is pretty explicit on how to resolve the situation: once your files have no merge markers in them (and are added/committed), the merge is complete, and you can start a new one.

Comment: I finally fixed the error. I will add it as edit to your answer.

Comment: Here is the solution - `git add .`, `git commit - m "success"`, `git merge master`. Link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961752/git-merge-error-commit-is-not-possible-because-you-have-unmerged-files

Comment: @sidsmith great! I'm outside right now. I will include your solution in the answer when I get back.