# What is a git workflow

Tags: git, workflow, git-branch

What's a git workflow and where do I need to write it? **Paper**? **Git Diagram**?
I've seen a lot of websites, threads and I don't know what is a git worfklow and where do I need to write the workflow. I think it's a good idea to begin to use the workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A git workflow doesn't necessarily need to be in a formal paper or diagram. It's simply a way that your team uses git, generally concerning branches or commit messages.

Comment: Ok, so worflows are like rules?

Comment: Sort of. They're basically popular conventions, though they aren't built into git. A workflow is simply a collection of conventions you use for storing and versioning files in git.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have 2 workflows to consider in a *distributed* version control system like Git:

- the **merge workflow** (common to any VCS, Version Control System): what do you merge, from which branch to which branch?
  This is a *local* workflow, and the most popular one is the **[git-flow](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/)**
- the **publication workflow**: where do you push, from where do you pull? You can see some of those workflows in the Atlassian article "[Comparing workflows](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/)".
  This is how you collaborate with others.

You can see more at:

- "[Sell me distributed revision control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2563917/6309)"
- "[Describe your workflow of using version control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2705286/6309)"

Comment: Since git workflows aren't really a formal concept, I would argue that it's more complicated than this. I've seen git workflows that involve adding extra syntax to git commit messages, and some that don't involve merges or publication practices.